# Copy data from one database to another using SQLPLUS/shell

Tags: sql, database, oracle, etl

I need to copy data from one of the remote database to data base in my server. But I am getting eroor below.

```
insert into table_here@oprdb select * from view_on_remote@AISPRD where rownum<10;

                                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
```

I also tried connecting to both before query:

```
conn schema/password@host:port/srvc_name;
conn schema/password@host:port/srvc_name1;
```

Trying the COPY command failed as well:

```
Array fetch/bind size is 15. (arraysize is 15)
Will commit when done. (copycommit is 0)
Maximum long size is 80. (long is 80)

CPY-0012: Datatype cannot be copied
```

But still it says connection description not found.

Can anyone help me where I am getting this wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [COPY](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/apb.htm#SQPUG140) command

```
--connect to target db    
sqlplus schema/password@host:port/oprdb
sqlplus>copy from schema/password@host:port/AISPRD insert table_here using -
select * from view_on_remote where rownum<10;
```

Comment: I have also tried COPY, but I have `datetime` column as well, so it fails.

Comment: "so it fails" not helpful at all.Please post relevant details and error message.Both target and source should have identical table structure or copy to staging table and insert into target.There is no datetime data type in Oracle.Are you copying between Oracle to Oracle?

Comment: It says "Data Type not supported" I will replicate the error and send you the exact error code

Comment: Also, I made typo, I have timestamp column in source data.

Comment: Copy command does not support timestamp. datatype.convert to to_char to staging table and insert into target table.